# Matlab or Origin - Combining two sets of 3D data in one contour plot

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, contour, originlab

I have two sets of 3D data with XYZ coordinates. I would like to know if there is a program that can combine the two, such that:

One set of data is represented by the colours of the plot, and the other set of data is represented by the height (in 3D) of the plot.

I am familiar with both Matlab and Origin.

Comment: Yes you can. Read about custom colormaps

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with `surf(Z,C)`.

```
a = randi(20,20,20);
b = randi(20,20,20);

figure;
subplot(2,2,1);
surf(a);
title('Height');

subplot(2,2,2);
surf(b);
title('Color');

subplot(2,2,[3,4]);
surf(a,b);
title('Mixed');
```

Not the best representations but you can see one matrix yields height and one yields color.

#### Color of mixed plot comes from right plot

[image: Color matches]

### Height of mixed plot comes from left plot

[image: Height matches]

Answer (score 0):

It is easy if you use scatter3 function.

```
w=100;
x1=rand(1,w);
y1=rand(1,w);
z1=rand(1,w)*100;
z2=ceil(rand(1,w)*255);
figure
h=scatter3(x1,y1,z1,ones(1,w)*50,z2,'filled');
```

[image]